# Copying directories to directories with different names

Tags: debian, ubuntu, files, directory, cp

How can I copy a number of directories:

```
directory_01
directory_02
directory_03
```

to different directories

```
tmp_directory_01
tmp_directory_02
tmp_directory_03
```

where each tmp_directory_* directory has the same content(files and subdirectories) as directory_*. For example tmp_directory_01 will have the same contents as directory_01.

Comment: You want to copy only the contents of `directory_x` to `tmp_directory_x` or you want to have `directory_x` as subdirectory of `tmp_directory_x` ?

Comment: @Serg The first one.

Comment: @Sebi then you may want to go with drewbenn's method , except I'd change the code to `cp -R "$d"/* "tmp_$d"`

Comment: @drewbenn post it as an answer

Comment: @serg, Did you test your code. I can not see how it can work.

Comment: @richard I meant to say to alter the `cp -R "$d" "tmp_$d"` part of drewbenn's code to `cp -R "$d"/* "tmp_$d"` since the OP wanted only the contents. Doing `cp dir1  dir2` gives dir2 as subdirectory to dir1. Do you see what I mean ?

Answer (score 1):

Posting comment as answer:

```
for d in directory_*; do cp -R "$d" "tmp_$d"; done
```

Credits @drewbenn